# Pass datas from Page to Page in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to pass the datas from page1 to page2. We can achieve this through code behind in Windows Phone...

Is there anyway to achieve this in 0% c# code and 100 % xaml code .. Any one guide me ?.. It would be really helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the Hyperlinkbutton

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/Page2.xaml?data=somedata" Content="click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you have state saved on the device itself (either in a database or serialized file).  Then you just save it on page change and open it on page open.